# Receiving status updates from cmd application

Tags: c#, events, process, cmd

I am using some microscopy software which can be remotely controlled using a small command line based application. To use this application more efficiently I would like to write my own piece of software for that using C#.

I already managed to connect to the main software using this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Process receiver = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "WSxMrc.exe",
            Arguments = "-m recv -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9602",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bConnect.Enabled = false;
        bDconnect.Enabled = true;

        receiver.Start();     
    }...
```

Using the application in the cmd, it receives now information whenever an image was acquired and so on. I would like to use these received statuses to act on whatever happened. For example, change the scan area after an image was captured.

I'm pretty sure I have to raise some sort of event to record the incoming status and that's where I'm stuck now. I have no idea how to create an event which recognizes whenever a new message is send to the receiver process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the OutputDataRecieved event to handle the redirected output.

Add these lines after reciever.Start()

```
receiver.OutputDataReceived += receiver_OutputDataReceived;
receiver.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

and then add the event handler

```
void reciever_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

More information can be found here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Seems to be what I was looking for. Unfortunately, didn't get it to work so far (also had a look at the msdn link). I will keep on tinkering around with it.